# Proper way to remove keys in dictionary with None values in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

What is the proper way to remove keys from a dictionary with value == `None` in Python?

Comment: You'll have to clarify what you mean, as every key in a dictionary must have a value, even if that value is `''` or `0` or `None`.

Comment: `{k: v for k, v in original.items() if v is not None}`

Answer (score 198):

Generally, you'll create a new `dict` constructed from filtering the old one.  dictionary comprehensions are great for this sort of thing:

```
{k: v for k, v in original.items() if v is not None}
```

If you *must* update the original dict, you can do it like this ...

```
filtered = {k: v for k, v in original.items() if v is not None}
original.clear()
original.update(filtered)
```

This is probably the most "clean" way to remove them in-place that I can think of (it isn't safe to modify a dict while you're iterating over it)

---

<sup><sup>Use `original.iteritems()` on python2.x</sup></sup>

Comment: Currently the other two answers to this question appear to be iterating over the dictionary while deleting from it.  Is that what you mentioned in the last sentence? Iterating over `dict.keys` or `dict.items`?

Comment: @RobertL -- Yeah.  Iterating over `dict` is always unsafe if you are going to be mutating the dictionary in the process.  Iterating over `dict.keys()` and `dict.items()` is fine on python2.x, but unsafe on python3.x.  See http://stackoverflow.com/a/6777632/748858 for example.

Comment: Thanks for updating with Python 3 syntax. As Python 2 becomes older, this answer becomes more clumsy. Perhaps it's time to provide the Python 3+ answer first and the legacy syntax as a footnote.

Comment: @JasonR.Coombs -- Agreed.  I flip-flopped this one to default to python3.x -- Actually that would work on python2.x as well, it'd just be slightly less efficient.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work if you have nested dictionaries

Comment: `ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)`; it doesn't like the `k, v` part

Answer (score 20):

if you need to delete None values recursively, better to use this one:

```
def delete_none(_dict):
    """Delete None values recursively from all of the dictionaries"""
    for key, value in list(_dict.items()):
        if isinstance(value, dict):
            delete_none(value)
        elif value is None:
            del _dict[key]
        elif isinstance(value, list):
            for v_i in value:
                if isinstance(v_i, dict):
                    delete_none(v_i)

    return _dict
```

with advice of [@dave-cz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2810747/dave-cz), there was added functionality to support values in list type.

[@mandragor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5039582/mandragor) added additional if statement to allow  dictionaries which contain simple lists.

Here's also solution if you need to remove all of the None values from dictionaries, lists, tuple, sets:

```
def delete_none(_dict):
    """Delete None values recursively from all of the dictionaries, tuples, lists, sets"""
    if isinstance(_dict, dict):
        for key, value in list(_dict.items()):
            if isinstance(value, (list, dict, tuple, set)):
                _dict[key] = delete_none(value)
            elif value is None or key is None:
                del _dict[key]

    elif isinstance(_dict, (list, set, tuple)):
        _dict = type(_dict)(delete_none(item) for item in _dict if item is not None)

    return _dict
```

The result is:

```
# passed:
a = {
    "a": 12, "b": 34, "c": None,
    "k": {"d": 34, "t": None, "m": [{"k": 23, "t": None},[None, 1, 2, 3],{1, 2, None}], None: 123}
}

# returned:
a = {
    "a": 12, "b": 34, 
    "k": {"d": 34, "m": [{"k": 23}, [1, 2, 3], {1, 2}]}
}
```

Comment: You need to add `list()` before `_dict.items()` to avoid raising a `RunTimeError` due to the dict changing size during iteration

Comment: value can be list of dicts with None properties, add `elif isinstance(value, list):
    for v_i in value:
        delete_none(v_i)`

Comment: There is no need to return _dict. This will only increase the runtime. _dict is passed by reference to the method. You can pass a copy of the dictionary you want to remove ones from to this function and get the result.

Comment: it is missing a case if you have an array on the top level: 
    mylist: [ 1, 2,3 ]

Comment: @Mandragor good point, thanks, it can't be checked in the very beginning like:
    if not isinstance(_dict, dict):
        return _dict
but your looks good

Comment: Could you clarify why this strategy is an advantage over using dictionary comprehensions (e.g. `{for k: v in k, v in d.items if v is not None}`?

Comment: @SenhorLucas how do u solve it for dict inside dict?list with dicts?

Comment: @vova, with list/dictionary comprehension inside a dictionary comprehension. You can nest them. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17915117/nested-dictionary-comprehension-python

Answer (score 4):

For `python 2.x`:

```
dict((k, v) for k, v in original.items() if v is not None)
```

Comment: I can't speak for the down-voter, but one issue with the answer here is that `not v` will evalute to `True` if `bool(v)` evaluates to `False`. This is the case for `v == ''` (empty string), for example, which is different from saying `v == None`.

Comment: @Rob `is not` is not equivalent to `is` and `not` combined. It is a separate operator altogether that tests Identity. See `operator.is_not`for [Python2](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.is_not) and [Python3](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.is_not).

Comment: @AminShahGilani Yes, the answer has been edited. It was previously using `if not v` rather than `if v is not None`. Should I delete my comment now?

Answer (score 4):

if you don't want to make a copy

```
for k,v  in list(foo.items()):
   if v is None:
      del foo[k]
```

Comment: Better is `foo.pop(k)` else it'll fail

Comment: FYI, the `list` keyword creates a (shallow) copy of the key/value pairs.

Comment: foo.pop(k) fails as well if there's no key, better, pop(k, None)

Answer (score 3):

You could also take a copy of the `dict` to avoid iterating the original `dict` while altering it.

```
for k, v in dict(d).items():
    if v is None:
        del d[k]
```

But that might not be a great idea for larger dictionaries.

Answer (score 2):

Python3 recursive version

```
def drop_nones_inplace(d: dict) -> dict:
    """Recursively drop Nones in dict d in-place and return original dict"""
    dd = drop_nones(d)
    d.clear()
    d.update(dd)
    return d

def drop_nones(d: dict) -> dict:
    """Recursively drop Nones in dict d and return a new dict"""
    dd = {}
    for k, v in d.items():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            dd[k] = drop_nones(v)
        elif isinstance(v, (list, set, tuple)):
            # note: Nones in lists are not dropped
            # simply add "if vv is not None" at the end if required
            dd[k] = type(v)(drop_nones(vv) if isinstance(vv, dict) else vv 
                            for vv in v) 
        elif v is not None:
            dd[k] = v
    return dd
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you'll find it useful:

```py
def clear_dict(d):
    if d is None:
        return None
    elif isinstance(d, list):
        return list(filter(lambda x: x is not None, map(clear_dict, d)))
    elif not isinstance(d, dict):
        return d
    else:
        r = dict(
                filter(lambda x: x[1] is not None,
                    map(lambda x: (x[0], clear_dict(x[1])),
                        d.items())))
        if not bool(r):
            return None
        return r
```

it would:

```
clear_dict(
    {'a': 'b', 'c': {'d': [{'e': None}, {'f': 'g', 'h': None}]}}
)

->

{'a': 'b', 'c': {'d': [{'f': 'g'}]}}
```