# How can I remove None value from python dictionary?

Tags: python, jmespath

I have the python dictionary like this

`data_dict = {'col_1': [{'size': 3}, {'classes': 'my-3 text-light text-center bg-primary'}, {'styles': [{'font-size': '14px'}]}]}`

Using [jmespath](https://jmespath.org/) library, I tried to achieve the desired result of dictionary like this

`{'size':3, 'classes':'my-3 text-light text-center bg-primary', 'styles':[{'font-size': '14px'}]}`

According to jmespath documentation [MultiSelect](https://jmespath.org/tutorial.html#multiselect), I ended up as this:

`jmespath.search('*[].{size:size, class:classes, styles:styles}', data_dict)`

As a result, I got unnecessary key/value pair of `None` value dictionary as so

`[{'size': 3, 'class': None, 'styles': None}, {'size': None, 'class': 'my-3 text-light text-center bg-primary', 'styles': None}, {'size': None, 'class': None, 'styles': [{'font-size': '14px'}]}]`

My question is how can I remove key/value `None` in order to get my desired result? Thanks.

Comment: see this post if that helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33797126/proper-way-to-remove-keys-in-dictionary-with-none-values-in-python

Comment: Here you have a very good answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33797126/proper-way-to-remove-keys-in-dictionary-with-none-values-in-python

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
NewDictList = []
res = [{'size': 3, 'class': None, 'styles': None}, {'size': None, 'class': 'my-3 text-light text-center bg-primary', 'styles': None}, {'size': None, 'class': None, 'styles': [{'font-size': '14px'}]}]
for dict_values in res:
    result = {key: value for key, value in dict_values.items() if value is not None}
    NewDictList.append(result)
print(NewDictList)
#result is [{'size': 3}, {'class': 'my-3 text-light text-center bg-primary'}, {'styles': [{'font-size': '14px'}]}]
```