# Python3 dictionary comprehension with sub-dictionary upacking?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, dictionary-comprehension, iterable-unpacking

Suppose one has a dictionary, `root` which consists of key:value pairs, where some values are themselves dictionaries.

Can one (and if so, how) unpack these sub dictionaries via dictionary comprehension?

e.g.

```
{k: v if type(v) is not dict else **v for k, v in root.items()}
```

example:

```
root = {'a': 1, 'b': {'c': 2, 'd': 3}}


result = {'a': 1, 'c': 2, 'd': 3}
```

Comment: Resulting in what? what is your expected output?

Comment: @DeepSpace updated to give clarity

Comment: `{_k: _v for k,v in root.items() for _k, _v in (v if isinstance(v, dict) else {k: v}).items()}`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Nested dictionary comprehension python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17915117/nested-dictionary-comprehension-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess I should post as an answer with a more broad explanation to help you as it is a little bit different to other existing questions

```
{
    _k: _v
    for k, v in root.items()
    for _k, _v in (         # here I create a dummy dictionary if non exists
                      v if isinstance(v, dict) else {k: v}
                  ).items() # and iterate that
}
```

The key part of understanding is that you need consistent and generic logic for the comprehension to work.

You can do this by creating *dummy* nested dictionaries where they don't previously exist using `v if isinstance(v, dict) else {k: v}`

Then this is a simple nested dictionary unpacking exercise.

To help in your future comprehensions I would recommend writing the code out e.g.

```
res = dict()
for k,v in root.items():
    d = v if isinstance(v, dict) else {k: v}
    for _k, _v in d.items():
        res[_k] = _v
```

and work backwards from this

## Useful references

- [Putting a simple if-then-else statement on one line](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2802726/4013571)
- [Nested dictionary comprehension python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17915117/4013571)

Answer (score 1):

If you have several levels of nested dictionaries, I suggest you the following solution based on a recursive function:

```
def flatten(res, root):
    for k,v in root.items():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            flatten(res, v)
        else:
            res[k] = v

root = {'a': 1, 'b': {'c': 2, 'd': {'e': 5, 'f': 6}}}

result = {}
flatten(result, root)

print(result)  # {'a': 1, 'c': 2, 'e': 5, 'f': 6}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a recursive solution. In the function `_flatten_into_kv_pairs`, we iterate through the key and values pair and yield those keys/values if the value is a not a dictionary. If it is, then we recursively call `_flatten_into_kv_pairs` with the `yield from` construct. The function `flatten_dict` is just a shell which turns sequence of key/value pairs back into a dictionary.

```
def _flatten_into_kv_pairs(dict_object):
    for k, v in dict_object.items():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            yield from _flatten_into_kv_pairs(v)
        else:
            yield k, v


def flatten_dict(dict_object):
    return dict(_flatten_into_kv_pairs(dict_object))


root = {'a': 1, 'b': {'c': 2, 'd': 3, 'e': {'f': 4, 'g': 5}}}
print(flatten_dict(root))
```

Output:

```
{'a': 1, 'c': 2, 'd': 3, 'f': 4, 'g': 5}
```