# How to add the sum of a list inside a nested dictionary, back into the dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

Let's say I have a nested dictionary in a dictionary, with that dictionary's value being a list.

How do I add the sum of the values inside the list? For example:

I would like the output to be dict = {one: {"a": 3, "b": 9}....}

```
dataset = {
  "one" : { "a" : [ 0, 1, 2 ], "b" : [ 2, 3, 4 ] },
  "two" : { "a" : [ 0, 1, 2, 3 ], "b" : [ 0, 1 ] }
}
```

Comment: you can use nested dictionary comprehension along with the function sum

Comment: I'm rather new to python - could you show me how to do it?

Comment: check out this very similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17915117/nested-dictionary-comprehension-python

Answer (score 1):

```
def transdict(d, func):
    return {*zip(d.keys(), [func(x) for x in d.values()])}

foo = transdict(dataset, lambda x: transdict(x, sum))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this way of indexing dictionary, and i think this is simpler than other methods mentioned here

```
dataset = {
    "one": {"a": [0, 1, 2], "b": [2, 3, 4]},
    "two": {"a": [0, 1, 2, 3], "b": [0, 1]}
}

#indexing your dataset by calling name of item and item inside dictionary
index = dataset['one']['a']
index2 = dataset['one']['b']
index3 = dataset['two']['a']
index4 = dataset['two']['b']

#Updating the item to sum of the list 
dataset['one']['a'] = sum(index)
dataset['one']['b'] = sum(index2)
dataset['two']['a'] = sum(index3)
dataset['two']['b'] = sum(index4)

#Printing the dictionary
print(dataset)
```

Result:

```
{'one': {'a': 3, 'b': 9}, 'two': {'a': 6, 'b': 1}}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a nested dictionary comprehension:

```
summed = {outer_k: {k:sum(v) for k,v in outer_v.items()}  
          for outer_k, outer_v in dataset.items()}
```

Result:

```
In [66]: summed                                         
Out[66]: {'one': {'a': 3, 'b': 9}, 'two': {'a': 6, 'b': 1}}
```